# CherryPy + Jinja, where to initialize Environment

Tags: python, cherrypy, jinja2

I'm writing an application in python using CherryPy and Jinja as the template system. May be needed to say that i'm a beginner with these tools.
The problem I'm facing now is I cannot figure where to initialize Jinja's Environment class.

Currently I have

- application.py (entry point, sets up Environment and starts server)
- root.py (root page class for cherrypy, must be imported from 'application.py', and must import 'application.py' to retrieve instantiated Enviroment)
- pages.py (other page classes for cherry.py, must import 'application.py', and must be imported from root to build the tree)

Trying to run that ends up in what seems to be a circular reference and fails (application > root > pages > application).

Should I stick to only one Environment instance or is it okay to have an instance at root.py and another in pages.py?

Which is the correct pattern for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really [repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If I were you I would create a new python module `templates.py` and put all the jinja environment configuration / creation there. Afterwards you can simply import that environment wherever you need it (e.g. `from templates import jinjaenv`). In this case you keep things simple and extensible for future use.

Comment: Good, but then templates module can be referenced by multiple modules. Does python know that 'jinjaenv' should be 'the same' instance object, or it simply instantiates a new one on each import?

Comment: It will be the same instance. All variables (classes, functions) defined in a module are shared. You can think of python modules as objects which are loaded once and then referenced with the help of import statement.